# find module(s) that contain given class or function (python)

Tags: python, search, module

is it possible? For, example, if I dont remember the name of module and I dont want to open google, I do

```
>>> findmodule('someclass')
'somemodule'
>>> from somemodule import someclass
```

Comment: "I dont want to open google" this is hardly a practical concern is it.

Comment: It might be possible, at least you can `import TAB` in ipython and it finds a way to list all modules. So you could check each module for that class.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to do some very fiddly searching of `sys.path`, import everything you can find there recursively, and search what you find. This is... really not how Python's imports are supposed to work. (Since the design is that modules are loaded as-needed.)

Comment: Use `pydoc` in a terminal

Comment: @millimoose See, I use bpython and it shows whats inside module/class when I want to import or use, so I thought, mabe there is some sort of index of the whole tree so I can search that tree, so thats why I'm asking ^_^

Comment: @Mattias pydoc -k is so pretty cool, but still I have to switch from the interpreter

Comment: @kitty `bpython` probably builds that index - it can even do so on-demand as you press TAB based on the context. (Listing all modules that are importable when you press `import <TAB>` is easier than scanning them recursively.) To the best of my knowledge there isn't such an index built into Python, and I doubt building that index is easy.